# dynamically add html tag in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I need to add html tags dynamically in asp.net code behind  , here is the scenario :

```
List<Product> products = ProductManager.GetProductList();//read data from database
```

`Product` is a class containing information I need to show in website such as  product name, image,… .
For adding html code I tried this to show 5 products per page :

```
String  finalHtmlCodeContainer="";
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
   String myBox= "<div class=\"box\"> </div>";
   finalHtmlCodeContainer+=mybox;
}
boxWrapper.InnerHtml=finalHtmlCodeContainer;
```

`boxWrapper` is a div that  would contain our 5 product info.up to now everything is ok but problem appears when insted of `"<div class=\"box\"> </div>"`,`myBox`contains long characters of html code , the original myBox should include this:

```
<div class="boxWrapper">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="rightHeader">rightHeader</div>
                        <div class="leftHeader">leftHeader</div>

                        <div class="article">
                            <img src="../Image/cinemaHeader.jpg" />
                            <p>
                              some text here <!--product.content-->  
                            </p>
                          </div><!--end of article-->

                        <div class="rightFooter"><span>rightFooter</span>
                            <div class="info">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>item1</li>
                                    <li>item2</li>
                                    <li>item3</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of rightFooter-->

                        <div class="leftFooter"><span>leftFooter</span>
                        </div><!--end of leftFooter-->

                    </div><!--end of box-->                 
                </div><!--end of boxWrapper-->
```

you see if i add `producet.atrributes` to code snippet above, it would be more messy,hard to debug ,  has less scalability  and... . what is your solution?

Comment: (preferably div-based please and using pure html instead of using panel,label etc.)

Comment: why you don't use `Repeater control` ?

Comment: @zey would you compare it or explain about please ?

Comment: it's depend on how you bind `products` list to `div` ! Can you show me how did you bind it ?

Comment: @zey for instance: `myBox="<div>"+products[1].content+"</div>"`

Comment: I need to switch to PHP or Node.js.I don`t know does it make any difference in your answer or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the underlying product.  If you are using web forms, I'd suggest using a data bound control that supports templating like the ListView or Repeater.   It gives you full control over the UI, and also supports reloading the UI in ViewState.  In your scenario, you'd have to build the UI on every postback.  The ListView or Repeater track it in ViewState.

If you are using MVC, well using a helper method can make this easier as you can stick the item template within and then use a foreach and render out the helper.

If you are talking doing it in JavaScript, then there are templating components for doing the same thing.

Comment: I`m using web forms , what is your suggestion , ListView or Repeater or JavaScript for this scenario ? besides i need to switch to PHP or Node.js ...

Comment: ListView is most flexible and should work well.  Put the boxwrapper markup in layout template and item template with the box markup.

Comment: If you are switching to node, then templating with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to Add repeater in your `<p>` tag ,

```
       <p>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpDetail">
          <ItemTemplate>
           <div class="box">
               <%# Eval("YourDataField") %>
           </div>
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:Repeater>
        </p>
```

And make your `products` list as Repeater's datasourse in code behind .

```
rpDetail.DataSource = products ;
rpDetail.DataBind();
```

Comment: why not using ListView?

Comment: This is your choice ! You can use both , I'm just showing the example :)